# How to use make / jom / nmake on Windows?

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make, nmake

I'm trying to get the git commit id at build time with make on Windows.

On Linux Debian I can do it with

```
var := $(shell git rev-parse --verify master)

all:
    echo ${var} > file.txt
    cat file.txt
```

But on Windows 10 I get:

```
Error: Invalid macro invocation found in Makefile line 4
```

I'm using [jom](https://wiki.qt.io/Jom) (a clone of [nmake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=msvc-170)) which came with Qt 5.15 version.

Is it possible to do that with jom/nmake?

Comment: It appears that nmake is not at all compatible with (gnu)make. For running programs, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/makefile-preprocessing?view=msvc-170 - it looks like the best you can do is run a program using square brackets and capture its output in a file at that time.

Comment: When we had such primitive tools, one trick was to have `make` run a makefile that generated a makefile and ran `make -f makefile.generated`. That is, use a whole process as an indirect variable. Klunky, but it works.

Comment: Try parenthesis instead of curlies.